# Checking syntax when enter is pressed in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I've added some vim configurations and I've lost the ability to check for syntax errors when pressing enter.

I think this worked by default and I used it with PHP.

Does anyone know which configuration should I implement in order to make this work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this plugin for Runtime syntax check for PHP, JS and many others: https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic

Map a key to the check command and you can see the errors in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vim runtime syntax checker for php: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Runtime_syntax_check_for_php